# Unknown namespace during build (but intellisense knows it)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, intellisense, signalr

I am currently working on a project with SignalR. On my production server, it is missing an automatically generated js-file in `~/signalr/hubs`.
I wanted to try this solution:
[SignalR not working on production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444664/signalr-not-working-on-production-server)

But when I try to add this line to my `application_start` method in `global.asax`, my project will not build anymore. Although intellisense knows and suggests the extension method!

I referenced the namespace with `using SignalR;`. I tried calling it as an extension method and calling it as a static method with the object instance as the first parameter.
The exact error messages:

When calling as extension method:

```
Error   1   'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for 'MapHubs' and no extension method 'MapHubs' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

When calling as static method:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'RouteExtensions' does not exist in the namespace 'SignalR' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Anybody knows why this happens and how to solve the problem? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this fail on your local or build machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it could be one of these reasons:

- Your project requires a reference to an assembly that's not added to the project.
- Is your project using the .NET Framework version that's compatible with the referenced assembly?

With your given info, it would be hard to determine the exact reason, but I believe that I provided you some helpful hints.

The fact that intellisense suggests you anything like an extension method won't mean that the project has the required references to work properly.

Comment: Thanks - when changing the .NET Framework version (to 4.5) of the project, it builds successfully!
I didn't expect that one can add a reference that needs a newer .NET version than the project itself... But for the future, now i know (: many thanks!

Comment: @Chips_100 No problem, I've been having such kind of problems during the last years and you catch these _on the fly_ haha :)